# Route a url to a directory with nginx

Tags: nginx

Let's say this is the ip of a server running nginx:

> 1.2.3.4

Let's also say I've purchased this url:

> www.abcd.com

I've edited the DNS records for **www.abcd.com** like so:

(Using Godaddy as a registrar)

> ***A (host)***
>
> Host  |  Points To | TTL
>
> @     |  1.2.3.4   | Live!

Entering **1.2.3.4** into my browser's url bar will take me to my server's nginx welcome page. Because I pointed my url at the same address **www.abcd.com** also takes me to the same page, though it resolves to **1.2.3.4**.

Here is my nginx config file:

> **sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf #=>**

```
http {
    include       /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*;

upstream appname {
  server unix:///data/apps/appname/shared/tmp/puma/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.abcd.com;
  root /public/rails/test;
#  keepalive_timeout 5;
}
}
```

On my server, I have the following structure:

```
~/public/rails/test/index.html
```

Here's what index.html contains:

> **sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf #=>**

```
<h1> It works! Routing from <i>www.abcd.com</i> has been successful! </h1>
```

**What I expect to happen:**

Visiting **www.abcd.com** would be forwarded to **1.2.3.4** by the nameserver. When the request arrives at **1.2.3.4**, nginx would see that it's come from **www.abcd** and serve this file to the user:

> ~/public/rails/test/index.html

In short:

www.abcd.com =>

## It works! Routing from *www.abcd.com* has been successful!

**What actually happens:**

Visiting **www.abcd.com** *is* forwarded to **1.2.3.4** by the nameserver. However, it's although my config file isn't working. It just displays nginx' "welcome" message to the user, as if I haven't touched my config file.

I've tried

> sudo service nginx stop
>
> sudo service nginx start

and

> sudo service nginx restart

and after editing the config, but different nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Where can I find logs to see exactly what's happening? What does nginx' welcome screen signify? That my paths are wrong? What? Flying blind here.

Answer (score 0):

Your server blocks root directive is set to **/public/rails/test** (absolute path), while you say you expect it to serve **~/public/rails/test/index.html** to the user. The character **~** indicates the current users home directory, and is a relative path.

Therefore: Try setting the absolute path (for example **/home/myuser/public/rails/test**) in the server block.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `server_name` with and without `www`
2. Add this line `index index.html;`
3. add `~` sign before `/public/rails/test`. Like: `root ~/public/rails/test;`

Try with this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abcd.com www.abcd.com;
  index index.html; # add this line
  root ~/public/rails/test; # add "~" sign '/public/rails/test'
  server_name www.abcd.com;
}
```